# 'Attribute error' when installing matplotlib on OS X

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I'm trying to install the latest version of `matplotlib` on OS X Mavericks. I followed the both install methods on the matplotlib website: the `easy_install -m matplotlib` method, and `git clone` install from source method.

I get this error when I try to install using either method:

```
AttributeError: 'Configuration' object has no attribute 'add_define_macros'
```

Any idea what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have updated you `numpy` to the latest version:
`sudo pip install -U numpy`.